# relational database design for scale questions

Tags: database, scale

I need to store scale question (rate item on a scale of ...) data in SQL Server. The current database structure is:

**questions**

QuestionID

Question

**question options**

QuestionID

OptionID

OptionDescription

**user responses**

UserID

QuestionID

OptionID

The scale questions have a range from -100 to 100. I can generate the sequence of numbers in the range in order to enforce referential integrity. Is it the best way of doing it in order to ensure the data accuracy? Is there a better way of doing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a before insert/update trigger to check the values.  This way you wouldn't necessarily be bound to a constraint (other questions might need a different type of response).

Another solution would be to write a stored proc to do inserts/updates.  That way you could check the values within the stored proc before updating the table.
But I think it depends on your uses, and whether or not we need to be able to store other types of responses as well.

Another option would be to get a little creative with you option table and include MIN and MAX value, and then do a CONNECT BY LEVEL statement to get the different values, something like this (Oracle):

```
WITH RECS AS 
 (
    SELECT 'OPTION A' AS ANSWER_OPTION
    , 1 AS MIN_VALUE
    , 100 AS MAX_VALUE
 FROM DUAL
 ) 
SELECT ANSWER_OPTION
, ROWNUM AS OPTION_VALUE
FROM RECS
CONNECT BY LEVEL  BETWEEN MIN_VALUE AND  MAX_VALUE
```